# Calendar View Remove Duplicate Items

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I'm using [Calendar module](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) to display a list of nodes with fields related to that specific days. I am handling multiple date fields using contextual filters.
For example, if an item has a Preview Date of 7/1 and a Review Date of 7/2, the node item will show for each date.
The problem is each node item is showing for each date, i.e. 7/1  and 7/2 show the item twice.

How do I remove the duplicate items? So each date only shows one of each node? I've tried aggregated fields/Count Distinct and Query Distinct but had no sucess.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [views distinct module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct)
from module page:

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate" results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically distinct. This module aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or aggregate these "duplicate" rows.

I hope it helps, be carefull in features, the module settings are not exported in features. If you use features, once you push your code, on production site, set your view UI settings again, it's easy and simple.

Comment: I installed Views Distinct, it looks like it gives me the option to remove duplicate row within an item but not duplicate items themselves